# Integration of non holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f$ is a holomorphic function in $D(0, p)$ and let $\gamma(t) = re^{it}, 0≤t≤2\pi$, with $0 < r < p$. If $b$ is not in $D(0,p)$,  and $z-b$ is not holomorphic then $\int_{\gamma}\dfrac{f(z)}{z-b} dz = 0$

I don't understand why that is true

Comment: How can  $z-b$ be non holomorphic? Is $b$ a complex constant?

Comment: @ajotatxe sorry for the lack of details, I edited my post

Comment: But, still, the function $z\mapsto z-b$ is holomorphic. (Then the statement is trivially true, but I guess that this is not what you mean).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have copied the statement from a book, lecture notes or something.

It seems a typo. It is true that $\int_\gamma\frac{f(z)}{z-b}dz=0$. But the reason is that $f$ is holomorphic in a disc that contains the image of $\gamma$ and $z-b$ *is not zero* in this disc. Hence $f(z)/(z-b)$ is holomorphic, too.